# Make a loop to write the contents of some variables in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using the Selenium IDE to store the values of a table in a page in some variables and then type the text in those variables in a text box, one per line.

The problem is that when I loop through the variable `${card}` the contents of the variable replace themselves while they should be one at a line.

I would also like to know if I'm using the right tool for doing this. Should I be using the Selenium Webdriver or something else?

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://es.magiccardmarket.eu/" />
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>https://eu.magiccardmarket.eu/?mainPage=browseUserProducts&amp;idCategory=1&amp;idUser=13786</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>target1</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeTable</td>
    <td>//div[@id='siteContents']/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/table.${x}.2</td>
    <td>card${x}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>new Number(${x}) + 1</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>storedVars['x'] &lt; 31</td>
    <td>target1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_text_box_code.cfm</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>target2</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['card' + storedVars['x']]</td>
    <td>card</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=comments</td>
    <td>${card}<br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>new Number(${x}) + 1</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>storedVars['x'] &lt; 31</td>
    <td>target2</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to your question regarding the "right tool", Selenium WebDriver is used for full-scale regression suites.  I think the task at hand is just fine for using IDE.. the IDE is for quick, short automations.  Exactly what you are doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type sets the value of an input field. So each time you call type it's only setting it to the 3rd column.

Something like this:

```
<tr>
<td>storeValue</td>
<td>name=comments</td>
<td>com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>name=comments</td>
<td>${com}\n${newvalue}</td>
</tr>
```

Or you can build up the var and use the type command once.
Frankly I would do this looping in javascript rather than use flow control, which I don't like.

Comment: Could you put how the loop would be using javascript?

Comment: Something like this:
var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
var mystring ='';

for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  if(row.cells[2]) {
    mystring += row.cells[2].lastChild.innerHTML + "\n";
  }
}

console.log(mystring);

But my fix is probably easier for you at this point...